# Use a certain div ID to select a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some jQuery which is getting the ID of an element on the page when it is clicked. I want to use that ID in order to select which variable to use in my JS.

For example:

I click on the element with ID 'a'.
I have a variable called 'a', I want to use this variable for DOM because the user clicked the 'a' element.

Comment: Please show us your code

Comment: you can't access a dynamic variable name like that unless it is in the global scope(because then it will be property of the window object - wouldn't recommend it)... instead if those are properties of an object then you can use the bracket notation

Comment: What do you mean by *"I want to use this variable for DOM"* ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have your variables on the global scope:

```
var a = "foobar",
    b = "barfoo";
```

Then this should work:

```
$('#a, #b').on('click', function(){
    console.log(window[this.id]); // "foobar" or "barfoo" when clicking #a or #b
});
```

You can access variables on the global scope, via the `window` object.

However, it seems elements with `id`'s are saved as properties on the widow object, so a object containing all your variables would be a better idea:

```
var props = {a: 1, b: 2};
```

Then:

```
console.log(props[this.id]);
```

**[Fiddle example](http://fiddle.jshell.net/BDAG4/1/)**

Comment: This is currently just returning undefined? The ID and the variable names are definitely right.

Comment: Can you `console.log(this.id)` and `console.log(a , b)`, in that click handler? It seems like the variables aren't on the global scope

Comment: Could the person that downvoted me please tell me why? If I made a mistake, I'd like to learn from it.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but `$('#a, #b')` simply looks for elements with ID `a` and `b`, not for whatever is contained in the variables with the same name. You have to use string concatenation. Also, if that's really what the OP's asking for, then it is a duplicate.

Comment: The variables that I'm trying to access are global variables. console.log(a) returns the contents of a, console.log(this.id) just returns blank.

Comment: @TheBritishBloke: Do the elements you're clicking actually _have_ and `id` attribute?

Comment: Oh, now I see what you are trying to do here... I guess the question wasn't clear to me.

Comment: Sorry I didn't realise I'd done this. I've used this to select the id of a parent element `order = $(this).closest('div[class^="item"]').attr('id');` That variable contains the ID of the element I want to use. So in this case it contains 'a'.

Comment: @TheBritishBloke: Then use that instead of `this.id`.

Comment: Indeed, @TheBritishBloke, in that case `props[order]` should be the variable you want.

Comment: I seem to have got this working, is it possible to use arrays within an object? Such as `var props = { a: ['Item 1','Item 2'],b: ['Item 3','Item 4']}` ? I've tried doing `console.log(props[order[0]]);` but it still returns all values in the array

Comment: @TheBritishBloke: Yea, it is, exactly like that! The "value" of key:value pairs in objects can be anything: Numbers, String, Booleans, Arrays, Objects, Functions (did I miss anything?)

Comment: Managed to get it all working! Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of keeping many variables, keep a single hash
like this

```
var hash = {}
```

now if user clicks div with id = 'a'
check for

```
hash['a']
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something like this

```
     $('.someclass').click(function(){
           var a = $(this).attr('id');
           // Say you want to show some div with id say 'xyz_check1';
           $('#xyz_'+a).show();
     });
```

Or use 'this.id'

The class '.someclass' should be common to all the elements which you want to use.

```
     <div class='someclass' id = "check1"></div>
     <div class='someclass' id = "check12"></div>
```

Comment: `$(this).attr('id');`? Use `this.id`. Also, _"ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".")."_

Comment: Right. I was giving him a idea about how he can go about that issue.

Comment: @Cerbrus: The ID can contain almost any characters in HTML5.

Comment: @FelixKling: True, but that doesn't mean it a good idea. Hm, but I can see how that quote of mine seems like a "rule", though.

Answer (score 0):

See Cerbrus' answer for accessing global variables via the `window` object for a better way of doing this. I didn't know you could access global variables this way - you learn something new every day!

My original answer is below:

```
// Replace the first line with selectors for each element you want to monitor the click event
$('#a, #b, #c').on('click', function() {
    switch ( this.id ) {
        case 'a':
            // Do something with 'a' variable
            break;
        case 'b':
            // Do something with 'b' variable
            break;

        // etc...

        case default:
            // Do something by default (if required)
            break;
    }
});
```

I prefer `.on('click', function(){ ... });` to `.click(function(){ ... });` as it allows support for any element which may have been dynamically added to the page post DOM compilation.

Comment: Yea, that's exactly what I answered already, except that you're using `$(this).attr(id)` instead of simply using `this.id`, and you're hardcoding `id` -> variable references.

Comment: I've changed to `this.id`, and there were no answers on this question when I began typing my answer... Why the downvote?

Comment: I've updated my answer to point reference to yours as the preferable option - I wasn't aware you could access global variables that way. I'm still learning too! :)

Comment: It seems there 's a little conflict in variables, in this case, though. Elements with `id`  attributes are accessible on the `window` object, too. `window['a']` actually logged the entire `<span id="a">A</span>`, in a fiddle test, for me, instead of the variable.

Comment: I see it's all working now though, good stuff!

Answer (score -1):

let us say,

```
$("div").click(function() {
    var divId = this.id ; // this will return you the ID of the div
    // divId will contain the variable you want to use
})
```

Comment: When the div is clicked, you get the id of the div and then look for the element with that id?  You mean the div?

Comment: Err sorry.. misunderstood, He wanted to use that variable which in this case is divId